# Column variabels are changed when making a data partition

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I have the following dataset:

```
head(filter_selection)
MATCHID COMPETITION            TEAM1              TEAM2 GOALS1 GOALS2 RESULT    EXPG1 EXPG2     DATUM     TIJD VERSCHIL
1 1696873  Pro League   Standard Liège Sporting Charleroi      3      0  TEAM1  1.57  0.61 25-7-2014 18:30:00     0.96
2 1696883  Pro League Waasland-Beveren        Club Brugge      0      2  TEAM2  1.29  1.18 26-7-2014 16:00:00     0.11
3 1696879  Pro League           Lierse        KV Oostende      2      0  TEAM1  1.03  1.04 26-7-2014 18:00:00    -0.01
4 1696881  Pro League         Westerlo            Lokeren      1      0  TEAM1  1.76  1.24 26-7-2014 18:00:00     0.52
5 1696877  Pro League         Mechelen               Genk      3      1  TEAM1  1.60  1.23 27-7-2014 12:30:00     0.37
6 1696871  Pro League       Anderlecht  Mouscron-Péruwelz      3      1  TEAM1  1.27  0.62 27-7-2014 16:00:00     0.65
```

I want to use the VERSCHIL value to predict the RESULT. Therefore I do the following to create a test/training  set:

```
library(rcaret)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=filter_selection$RESULT, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
```

Thing is however that when I do this my RESULT column changes:

```
training <- df_final_test[inTrain, ]
testing <- df_final_test[-inTrain, ]
head(training, 20)

MATCHID   COMPETITION              TEAM1              TEAM2 GOALS1 GOALS2  RESULT EXPG1 EXPG2     DATUM     TIJD VERSCHIL CLAS type           TYPE  TYPE2
1  1696873    Pro League     Standard Liège Sporting Charleroi      3      0          3  1.57  0.61 25-7-2014 18:30:00     0.96 0.96  TBD (-0.0767,1.54]   HIGH
2  1696883    Pro League   Waasland-Beveren        Club Brugge      0      2         4  1.29  1.18 26-7-2014 16:00:00     0.11 0.11  TBD (-0.0767,1.54] MEDIUM
```

It's now 3 and 4 in stead of TEAM1 and TEAM2. Could anybody tell me why the TEAM1 value changed into 3?

Its strange cause when I do the same with the spam dataset it works fine

```
data(spam)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=spam$type, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
training <- spam[inTrain, ]
head(training)
```

And that taking into consideration that the classes are the same

```
 class(spam$type)
 [1] "factor"
 class(filter_selection$RESULT)
 [1] "factor"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no package rcaret.
Secondly, you create a datapartition on "filter_selection", but then you create the training and test sets based on a different dataframe "df_final_test".

But do check the structure of df_final_test$RESULT and see how many levels the factor has. Maybe something went wrong there. If there are any levels in there you do not want use `droplevels(df_final_test$RESULT)`

If I try the code on the filter_selection and create a training set out of this one, I get a correct training and test set.

```
library(caret)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=filter_selection$RESULT, p=0.75, list=FALSE)

training <- filter_selection[inTrain, ]
testing <- filter_selection[-inTrain, ]
head(training)

  MATCHID COMPETITION            TEAM1              TEAM2 GOALS1 GOALS2 RESULT EXPG1 EXPG2     DATUM     TIJD VERSCHIL
1 1696873  Pro League   Standard Liège Sporting Charleroi      3      0  TEAM1  1.57  0.61 25-7-2014 18:30:00     0.96
2 1696883  Pro League Waasland-Beveren        Club Brugge      0      2  TEAM2  1.29  1.18 26-7-2014 16:00:00     0.11
4 1696881  Pro League         Westerlo            Lokeren      1      0  TEAM1  1.76  1.24 26-7-2014 18:00:00     0.52
5 1696877  Pro League         Mechelen               Genk      3      1  TEAM1  1.60  1.23 27-7-2014 12:30:00     0.37
6 1696871  Pro League       Anderlecht  Mouscron-Péruwelz      3      1  TEAM1  1.27  0.62 27-7-2014 16:00:00     0.65
```